# java.lang.IllegalStateException: An attempt to save the global configuration was made before it was loaded

Tags: jenkins

after click on Manage Jenkins -> Configure System, Global Properties. Check Environment Variables. Set Name to `/Users/macpro/.qshell/qshell`. Set Value to `$PATH:$HOME/.qshell`. Then restart Jenkins. appear issue like below.how can this be fixed
[image]

Comment: Isn't it a common case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441139/how-to-fix-jenkins-java-lang-illegalstateexception-an-attempt-to-save-the-globa/68315307#68315307 ?